# How to make the code work faster when it has a big set of data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data of around 1000000 rows where there are around 500 ids. I need to save the data based on the ids in different text files. Initially the ids had ':' so had to replace those with '_' while saving the txt file. Now it takes 4-5 days for the python code to finish separating those and saving in separate files. How can i speed it up.

Data will be like this:

```
     ID      Value
0    AB:1     2
1    BC:1     0
2    BC:1     1
-----------
-----------
1000000 AB:2  4

the code:

for i in df.ID:
     subID = df[df['ID'] == i]  
     fName = i.replace(':','_')
     fName = fName.replace('/','_')
     file_directory = r'C:\------' %fileName
     np.savetxt(file_directory, subID.values, fmt = '%s', delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: your current code does not compile (extra `]`). Regardless, if you are limited to 500 IDs and the code is slow, why not use caching?

Comment: instead of `for i in df.ID:`, can't you just loop through the unique values of `df.ID`?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will try. As i am new to python i have to research a little bit more it seems.

Comment: At each iteration of your loop you're calling np.savetxt. I'm not familiar with numpy, but presumably you're opening, saving, and closing your file 1,000,000 times. Is it possible for you to perform and save your replacements in code and only write to the file once? Just a thought.

Comment: hmmm yes probably that's why it is taking time. but I m not so sure how to do that. Will try though. Thanks !

Comment: Also, instead of iterating over each string and doing the same replacement, how about adding a column `df['new_id']=df['ID'].str.replace(':','_')` then using the `new_id` column for your file names or something similar? Additionally, the code you provided doesn't have any `/` characters to replace or define `fileName`. Please provide a [mcve] with the fully reproducible example of what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your code it appears that ID has duplicates but in loop you are looping all ID without removing duplicates

```
uq_ids =list(df['ID']).unique())
for i in uq_ids:
    subID = dfdf['ID'] == i] 
    fName = i.replace(':','_')
    fName = fName.replace('/','_')
    file_directory = r'C:\------' %fileName
    np.savetxt(file_directory, subID.values, fmt = '%s', delimiter='\t')
```

try this I am sure it would reduce execution time

Comment: Worked !! Thank you so much. I removed the list because it said list doesnt have unique ids. But it worked . Thanks alot

Comment: Great.you welcome

Answer (score 0):

The number one rule for getting the best possible speed out of pandas dataframes and/or numpy arrays is to avoid for-loops. Instead use the built-in vectorized functions of pandas and numpy. For an in-depth explanation see [Fast, Flexible, Easy and Intuitive: How to Speed Up Your Pandas Projects](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/).

Applying this to your code example would result in something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Construct example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['AB:1', 'BC:1', 'BC:1', 'AB:2'],
    'Value': [2, 0, 1, 4],
})

# Perform replacements in the 'ID' column
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace(':', '_')

# For each group of values with identical ID ...
for id_no, group_df in df.groupby('ID'):
    # Write values to file (with the ID number in the file name)
    value_series = group_df['Value']
    file_name = f'{id_no}.csv'
    print(f"Writing file '{file_name}' ...")
    value_series.to_csv(f'{id_no}.csv', header=False, index=False)
```